# query in a powerpivot table to do a group by

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2010, excel-2013, powerpivot

I have  a table called `"purchase"` with the following data:

```
year   month    time    day_week    name    provider    service    purchase    revenue
```

I am using this data to make a pivot table. Then I have another table called `"active"`:

```
 name    provider    service    description    month    year    number_active
```

I used this data to create a separate pivot table.

Now I need a third pivot table with something like:

```
 number_active/revenue
```

and slice it vertically to by year. The problem is that I cannot create a relationship between the table because in Purchase I have the services by day and hour and in Active I have the services by month. I think I need to create another table that is a view of Purchase grouped by month.

I tried the following :

```
 home ->  From Database   ->  From analysis services or PowerPivot
```

But i have a error:

[image: http://imgur.com/KUeuUc0]

I'm not sure where to go from here.

How can I make this view grouped by month?

Comment: He/she probably didn't have enough rep to do it.

Comment: @pnuts Eh, it was just a guess. You could have earned the two points for editing the image into the post. I just went ahead and did it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create a new view of summarized data as a source. You just need to be able to summarize by date, and you can do this by adding a date dimension.

You can download one for free from the [Windows Azure marketplace](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/boyanpenev/datestream).

Once you have your date table, add a calculated column to the Active table in your Power Pivot model called Date that is =`[Month]&"/01/"&[year]`. Then change the data type to date.

Then do the same thing to your Purchase table. Next, create relationships from Active[Date] to Date[DateKey] and from Purchase[Date] to Date[DateKey].

You could make all of this go down to the time level and related it there instead (Power Pivot will assume midnight if you don't specify a time in your date column). But I'm simplifying since that is not needed for this one scenario.

Next make your two base calculated measures

- Number Active:=Sum(Active[number_active])
- Total Revenue:=Sum(Purchase[revenue])

I'm not sure what your number active means, so I'm assuming it is just a sum. You can adjust this calc if this is not the case.

Then make your final calculation: Revenue Per Active User:= [Number Active]/[Total Revenue]

Then you should be able to pull month and year into a pivot table along with this new calculated measure and your original measures (number active and revenue).